# different output with compilers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc, graph

I was solving a programming problem on a site. On my machine (Visual Studio 2010) a test case gives wrong result, while gives correct result on the site. I am not sure what is the compiler of the site's judge, but I think it is something like gcc or cygwin.

**THE CODE**

A graph problem. The graph here is represnted as a tree. The graph is directed, and doesn't contain loops. The solution is `(2 * sum of all edges - max path length from root)`

```
//     to-vertex & edge-length
vector<pair<int, int> > pr[100];
int dfs(int i) // to find max path length from root
{
    int mx = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < pr[i].size(); ++j)
        mx = max(mx, dfs(pr[i][j].first) + pr[i][j].second);
    return mx;
}

int PowerOutage::estimateTimeOut(vector <int> from_vertex,
                 vector <int> to_vertex, vector <int> edge_length)
{
    int tot = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < from_vertex.size(); ++i)
    {
        pr[from_vertex[i]].push_back(make_pair(to_vertex[i], edge_length[i]));
        tot += (2 * edge_length[i]);
    }
    return tot - dfs(0);
}
```

**THE TEST CASE**

```
from_vertex   {0,     0,   0,   0,   0}
to_vertex     {1,     2,   3,   4,   5}
edge_length   {100, 200, 300, 400, 500}
```

**Visual Studio returns: 2493**, **While the site's compiler returns the correct answer: 2500**.

Why the two results are different? I think there is some hidden bug (in my code) that appears in VS giving wrong answer but disapper in the other compiler. Should I determine the site's compiler and use it instead?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I have removed this macro

Comment: What is your fpu option selected? Precise, fast, strict?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık Sorry, what do you mean by "fpu option" ?

Comment: *"Should I determine the site's compiler and use it instead?"* -- Definitely not.  You should determine the problem with the code.

Comment: I meant what i gave in the answer below

Comment: VS2010 produces the result of 2500 here regardless of optimization/fpu settings. However, we can't see your `main()` or an [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite my first(wrong) assumption, OP has found out that it was 2500 already but the test-function had the flaw after i asked him "where is 2500 printed?".

Comment: How can you know rest of the program? Where is main() ?

Comment: Thaks. I didn't change anything of "fpu", since I have learned what is it only now.

Comment: How are you printing 2500 ?. Did changing the fpu option worked?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık Your last comment was the answer !! :) :) The function was returning 2500 in fact. The wrong was in testing code. I'm trying to know what was the wrong this it

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık How mush stupidness !! The wrong was that when the test cases are consecutive `pr` is not `clear()`ed from previous results!!

Comment: @Desolator: Do you mean the void test_case_4() part?